# autocomplete="new-password" displays sugestions from old passwords in v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-text-field where I want to write the password of the user in order to confirm his account, when I try to make autocomplete="new-password" it still sugests me passwords that are already saved in browser. I need to make autocomplete="new-password" and not autocomplete="off" because autocomplete="off" fills the textfield automatically with the password of the user.

What I want is to clear these sugesstions.
This is v-text-field:

```
            <v-text-field clearable :rules="passwordRules" v-model="password" ref="password" 
            class="form-control" :type="value ? 'password' : 'text'" 
            :label="this.$i18n.t('enterPassword')" outlined dense autocomplete="new-password"
            @keydown.prevent.enter="verifyPassword" @keydown="handlePasswordRuleReset"
            @focus="handlePasswordRuleReset" @blur="handlePasswordRuleReset" @click:append="() 
            => (value = !value)"  :append-icon="value ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye'">
            </v-text-field>
```

This is what I have:
[image: 1]

Comment: Check developer tools if input field type is password and check if this code is returning password.  `:type="value ? 'password' : 'text'"`

Comment: This code is returning just true or false value  when I click the eye btn.

Comment: I have the same issue is their any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem was occurred by `v-text-field` . I suggest that `v-input` instead

Comment: ``` v-input ``` is in the ``` <form> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the issue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field :style="passwordStyle" type="text" v-model="inputValue" />

    <v-btn
      class="ma-2"
      color="primary"
      @click="showPassword = !showPassword"
      :disabled="!inputValue"
    >
      {{ showPassword ? "Hide" : "Show" }}
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      showPassword: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    passwordStyle() {
      return {
        "font-family": this.showPassword ? "helvetica" : "password",
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@font-face {
  font-family: "password";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf);
}
</style>
```